# How can I detect gdb in windows c code?

Tags: c, windows, debugging, gdb

I want to turn certain debug statements on when i'm debugging with gdb and id rather not do it by hand. I found code using `ptrace` which will detect gdb on *nix, but that doesnt exist on windows. I am compiling with mingw gcc on windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows has a function named [`IsDebuggerPresent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680345.aspx). I'm not *sure* it'll work with gdb, but assuming it uses the normal Windows functions, it should be fine.

Comment: huh, i saw that function but didnt think it'd work. just tried it and it did, lol.